# Insert multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the SQL below. SQL return a `Users.Id` which are not found in `Order` table. I need to create Insert SQL and insert default order for these users. How to do that?

```
SELECT  Id
FROM    [User] WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM dbo.[Order])
```

Order table columns are

```
      Id , --  Random Number 
      UserId , -- Id from Select above
      FirstName ,
      LastName ,
      Credits
```

Comment: It would appear that your `Order` table is not fully normalized. Hint: I suspect that `FirstName` is a non-key attribute of a user and not an attribute of an order at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `dbo.[User]` has the `FirstName`, `LastName` and `Credits` columns you can do it like this:

```
Insert Into dbo.[Order] (UserId, FirstName, LastName, Credits)
SELECT  u.Id, u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.Credits
FROM    [User] u WHERE u.Id NOT IN (SELECT o.UserId FROM dbo.[Order] o)
```

You can see [here](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html) for another example. You might understand it :)

---

To generate the `Unique Id` use the [Identity Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Could you update your post because I do not understand how to insert other columns. Also how to generate Unique int ID for Order.Id column?

Comment: @Tomas I've altered my answer :)

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` constraint does not generate a "Unique int ID" nor a "Random Number"!

Comment: I need to generate Unique Id in SQL, I can't change field option.

Comment: Nevermind, I have found how to create unique id using sql left(replace(cast(newid() as varchar(36)), '-', ''), 10)